# Django: How to do required field validation on ModelChoiceField or Radio Button

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I want to run required field validate using the clean function in my form class. I also wanted to validate this with self.add_error to access the field in template.

my form.py

```
class Step2(forms.Form):
    special_purpose = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        empty_label=None,
        queryset=SpecialPurpose.objects.all(),
        to_field_name="id",
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'style': 'list-style:none'}),
        required=False
    )


def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    special_purpose = cleaned_data.get("special_purpose")

    if special_purpose is '':
        self.add_error('special_purpose', 'This field is required')
```

then in my template

```
  <label id="{{ form.special_purpose.id_for_label }}-error" class="error" for="{{ form.special_purpose.name }}">{{ form.special_purpose.errors|striptags }}</label>

{{ form.special_purpose.0 }}<br>
{{ form.special_purpose.1 }}<br>
{{ form.special_purpose.2 }}<br>
{{ form.special_purpose.3 }}<br>
```

Is there a specific way for doing this for Radio buttons/ModelChoice field

Answer (score 0):

Thank to my buddy Waleed!

the mistake was in the if condition
if special_purpose is '':

this should be
if special_purpose is None:

as in the form declaration  i used emplty_label as None